# Add Events to Yahoo using curl

Tags: php, curl, yahoo-api

I've tried using curl to add new events to yahoo, succeeded in logging in and getting the calendar add events page, but when i try to post events using curl, it redirects me to login page. Please suggest what can i do...?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Yahoo! Calendar web application most likely has mechanisms in place to prevent scripted access or screen scraping.

You might try the published API for accessing Yahoo! Calendar through the [CalDAV](http://caldav.calconnect.org/) interface:
http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/calendar/yahoocalendar/misc/misc-01.html